# Exception mechanism doesn't work after some times

Tags: python, discord.py, try-except

I've created a Discord bot in Python using the discord.py library. This is the pseudo-code of my bot :

```
import discord


client = discord.Client()


async def test_func():
    return "This is a test"


async def error_func():
    raise Exception


text_to_func = {"test": test_func, "error": error_func}


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("$"):
        command = message.content[1:]
        try:
            func = text_to_func[command]
            answer = await func()
        except Exception:
            answer = "Error !"
        await message.reply(answer)


client.run("<TOKEN>")
```

When a message is received by the bot, the `on_message` function is executed. It checks if the message starts with "$", which is the prefix of my bot, and execute the function associated with the command in a try/except block.

I run this script on a ubuntu server using an ssh connection.

Now if I send "$test" on my discord server, the bot will reply with "This is a test" and if I send "$error", it will reply with "Error !". The thing is, after a certain amount of time (can be from 6 hours to 2 days), the "$error" command won't work anymore. The bot doesn't reply to the command, while it still does for "$test".

Does someone know what's going on there ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are using "except" wrong, it is either `except:` or `except except discord.DiscordException:` please google how to use `except`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're saying. Should I replace "except Exception:" with "except discord.DiscordException:"? How will this fix my problem? Thanks

Comment: Yes, or else use a error handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if you're actually just trying to react to errors, I recommend just using:

```py
@client.event
async def on_error(event, args, kwargs):
    #what you want to happen in the event of an error
```

instead of putting everything you do in a try...except block.

[Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_error) are the official docs for the on_error event listener.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will test it tomorrow and I hope it will solve my problem!

Comment: Unfortunately it gives the same problem, but thank you for your suggestion